# Loading an XSL Transform file in ASP

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt, asp-classic

Folks....This is an edited version which was originally post as a "Classic ASP" question.  It is basically ASP code but in an ASPX file and formatted to meet ASPX rules, ie no "Set " statements, etc.  However, as was coded in an ASPX file, some folks objected to calling it "Classic ASP".  OK, the question still stands, what am I doing wrong in the page as I try to load an XSL transform to sort my XLM?...

I'm trying to load an XSL transform file to sort my XML file using ASP.  The rest of the page is processing the XML file just fine, but for reasons I can not determine it seems to refuse to load, or perhaps even see, my XSL transform file.  I know the file is there as I can enter the URL in a browser and it will display and I can also use the "Scripting.FileSystemObject" to retrieve and output the text.  Here is my XSL file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/Sensors" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="sensor">
                <xsl:sort select="@location"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="sensor">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="reading">
                <xsl:sort select="@label"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the code below I output the XLM string twice: after loading it in initially (XMLDOC.text) and then after the transform (XSLT.text).  I also output the string from the load of the xsl file (XSLDOC.text), but it is always blank. XMLDOC.text and XSLT.text outputs are identical.

```
FileName = Server.MapPath("/" & "Sandbox/WeatherXLM.xml")   
xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmldoc.setProperty ("ServerHTTPRequest", true)
xmlDoc.setProperty ("ProhibitDTD", False)
xmlDoc.setProperty ("SelectionLanguage", "XPath")   
xmlDoc.validateOnParse = true
xmlDoc.async = "False"
xmlDoc.load(FileName)
    Select Case xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode
    Case 0 
                strResult = "Valid: " & FileName & vbCr
    Case Else
                strResult = vbCrLf & "ERROR! Failed to validate " & _
                FileName & vbCrLf & xmlDoc.parseError.reason & vbCr & _
            "Error code: " & xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode & ", Line: " & _
                       xmlDoc.parseError.line & ", Character: " & _
                       xmlDoc.parseError.linepos & ", Source: " & _
                       Chr(34) & xmlDoc.parseError.srcText & _
                       Chr(34) & " - " & Now & vbCrLf
        response.write ("<p>" & strResult & "</p>")
        End Select
response.write("<p> -->" & xmlDoc.text & "<-- </p>")
 'Load xls transform file
xslFileName = Server.MapPath("/" & "Sandbox/Sort2.xsl")
xslDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xslDoc.async = "False"
xslDoc.load(xslfilename)
    Select Case xslDoc.parseError.errorCode
    Case 0 
                strResult = "Valid: " & xslFileName & vbCr
    Case Else
                strResult = vbCrLf & "ERROR! Failed to validate " & _
                xslFileName & vbCrLf & xslDoc.parseError.reason & vbCr & _
            "Error code: " & xslDoc.parseError.errorCode & ", Line: " & _
                       xslDoc.parseError.line & ", Character: " & _
                       xslDoc.parseError.linepos & ", Source: " & _
                       Chr(34) & xslDoc.parseError.srcText & _
                       Chr(34) & " - " & Now & vbCrLf
        response.write ("<p>" & strResult & "</p>")
        End Select
response.write("<p>  2==>" & xslDoc.text & " <== </p>")
 'Transformed XLM and create the tables
xslt = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xslt.loadxml(xmlDoc.transformNode(xsldoc))
response.write("<p>  3==>" & xslt.text & " <== </p>")
    response.flush
%>
```

And, as I said above, the rest of the page processes the resulting XLM string (XSLT.text) correctly.

I have also tried other XML controls (Msxml2.DOMDocument, Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument) with the same result.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't you just use  response.write("<p>  3==>" & xmlDoc.transformNode(xslDoc) & " <== </p>")

Comment: you have errors in your page. for example: `xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")` should be `set xmlDoc = ...`

Comment: The problem is not with the "response.write("<p>  2==>" & xslDoc.text & " <== </p>")" statement, but, it seems, that the xslDoc.test string is empty??

Comment: My "Classic ASP" page is an ASPX file so that the server wants to process it as a .Net page.  .NET does not allow the use of "Set"

Comment: May I ask why your file has the .aspx extension?  If you want the server to execute Classic ASP code then you need to give it an .asp extension so that the server knows what to do with it

Comment: OK, I figured it out and it was what I expected, A VERY DUMB TYPO.  Thanks for your time and comments